# Why isn't the value written to the block in my very basic example?

Tags: solidity

Sorry for the wide headline, but my problem seems almost silly to me. I'm trying to get into solidity and it looks very basic to me.

Essentially that I have two funcs (and I tested it exactly like this):

```
... more contract here 

  mapping(address => address) ownerToDataProvider;

  function foo(address _account) external {
    ownerToDataProvider[msg.sender] = _account;
  }

  function bar() external view returns(address) {
    return ownerToDataProvider[msg.sender];
  }

... more contract here
```

And this test:

```
// contract is the deployed contract and dp is some address, so is user
console.log(dp)
await contract.foo(dp, {from: user})
const result = await contract.bar()
console.log(result)
```

The logged output is

```
0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

These should be equal, right? Why aren't they?

I use latest truffle and ganache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your not passing `from` address to bar(). While inserting your msg.sender is nothing but from in your case.

```
ownerToDataProvider[msg.sender] = _account
```

So, while calling bar(), from value is 0x000 address, there is no value in map so it will return 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Fix:

```
const result = await contract.bar({from: user})
```

ownerToDataProvider[msg.sender] is user, so you will get `0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732`

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
const result = await contract.bar({from: user})
```

Specifying the account that calls your `bar()` function